# htaccess rewrites my css and js, even source wont change

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am trying to learn VueJS and Twig. I made my own (just for fun) MVC and that is working fine, the problem lies in not being able to include JS or CSS files.

When I press CTRL+U and view my source, I click on my javascript file and then the page reloads with the correct URL but I will still see my index pagina...

I have no clue what is causing this and -or how to fix this. Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

root
htaccess
    public
    htaccess

My root htaccess file is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -Multiviews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

and the htaccess file in my public folder is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -Multiviews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /public
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}% !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}% !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

My layout (index) page is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Beta</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../public/css/style.css" />
    <script src="../../node_modules/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../public/js/scripts.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

{% block content %}{% endblock %}

</body>
</html>
```

As said, when I click on my CSS or JS file I see this in the source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Beta</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../public/css/style.css" />
    <script src="../../node_modules/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../public/js/scripts.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    Hello there!

</body>
</html>
```

Hope someone can help me out!

UPDATE:
I changed my htaccess to this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -Multiviews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

And now my CSS and JS are visible, but the node_modules (Vue) still shows this weird behavior of just showing the index page's source code.

Answer (score 0):

Obvious rookie mistake!

You cannot include something from the "node_modules" folder. I used GULP to include and compile everything to one of my publically accessible folders and now I can include them perfectly fine!